# Create world map with a specific extent using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to build a world map from the `map_data` ggplot2 function, and then crop it to a specific extension.

I am trying to build a world map with this **extension**:

```
ext <- data.frame(xmin = -10.57514, xmax = 37.21653, ymin = 29.68319, ymax = 73.22486)
```

The code that I have used is this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(map_data("world"), aes(long, lat)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group), color = "white", fill = "lightgray", size = 0.2) +
  theme_void() +
  coord_fixed() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(ext$xmin, ext$xmax)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(ext$ymin, ext$ymax))
```

This results in:

[image]

As you can see, the bottom of the plot (i.e, most of North Africa) is **not accurate**.

How would you fix that? Many thanks

Comment: I think the time where it's acceptable to call *this* a "World map" is long past. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to put the x and y limits into `coord_fixed`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(map_data("world"), aes(long, lat)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group),
               color = "white",
               fill = "lightgray",
               size = 0.2) +
  theme_void() +
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(ext$xmin, ext$xmax),
              ylim = c(ext$ymin, ext$ymax))
```

**Output**

[image]